# Questionnaire tool to create config files

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration

I have an application that needs a configuration file with several inputs which depend on the project that is going to be delivered. Things that are included in this conf file are IP's of databases, activating certain functions depending on the customer's needs, changing the values of some title screens, etc... A short example of a file could be something like:

```
postgresdb=192.156.98.98
transactions.enabled=true
application.name="client-1-logistics"
historicaldb=196.125.125.16
....
```

This files can become large and it might be difficult to find which parameters must be changed, specially if the configuration process has to be done by an external department.

I was looking into some kind of tool or framework that allows you to create some sort of questionnaire by which the user answers yes or no questions and fills out boxes with specific IP's or messages and get as a result the configuration file needed. This would be much tidier as you could group the questions into sections and has the potential of customising the configuration process with more context on the different parameters.

Does anyone know of such a framework?. How do you handle this kind of complex configuration processes?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I outline below is not exactly what you are looking for, but it might provide some food for thought.

1. Use a *template engine* (example, [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/index.html), or any of the
   [several dozen listed in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines)) to create a templated
   version of your configuration file, containing lots of boilerplate
   configuration that won't change, with the occasional
   `${variable_name}` placeholder (the syntax for a placeholder will
   vary from one template engine to another).
2. Write a small metadata file containing `variable_name=value`
   settings.
3. Write a trivial program that: (a) parses the metadata file and loads
   the `variable_name=value` settings into a `Map` (the template engine
   might refer to the `Map` as, say, a *context* object); (b) uses the
   template engine to parse the template file; (c)
   merges/evaluates/instantiates the parsed template file with the settings in
   the `Map`; and (d) writes the result to the target
   configuration file.

You might be able to use steps 1 and 3 above without change. It is only step 2 that you need to adapt to your questionnaire requirements. Instead of a questionnaire, perhaps you could give users a document that explains how to write the metadata file.